# Firebird - How to use "(? is null)" for selecting blank parameters

Tags: sql, excel, parameters, null, firebird

I am working with an Excel Report linked to a Firebird 2.0 DB and I have various parameters linked to cell references that correspond to drop down lists.

If a parameter is left blank, I want to select all the possible options.  I am trying to accomplish this by putting **... WHERE... (? is null)**, as described in http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd25-sqlnull.html ,  but I get an "Invalid Data Type" error.

I found some Firebird documentation (http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq92/) where it talks about this error, but it states that *"The solution is to cast the value to appropriate datatype, so that all queries return the same datatype for each column."* and I'm not quite sure what that means in my situation.

```
SELECT C.COSTS_ID,
       C.AREA_ID,
       S.SUB_NUMBER,
       S.SUB_NAME,
       TP.PHASE_CODE,
       TP.PHASE_DESC,
       TI.ITEM_NUMBER,
       TI.ITEM_DESC,
       TI.ORDER_UNIT,
       C.UNIT_COST,
       TI.TLPE_ITEMS_ID
FROM TLPE_ITEMS TI
  INNER JOIN TLPE_PHASES TP ON TI.TLPE_PHASES_ID = TP.TLPE_PHASES_ID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN COSTS C ON C.TLPE_ITEMS_ID = TI.TLPE_ITEMS_ID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN AREA A ON C.AREA_ID = A.AREA_ID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN SUPPLIER S ON C.SUB_NUMBER = S.SUB_NUMBER
WHERE ((C.AREA_ID = 1 OR C.AREA_ID = ?) OR **(? IS NULL))**
  AND ((S.SUB_NUMBER = ?) OR **(? IS NULL))**
  AND ((TI.ITEM_NUMBER = ?) OR **(? IS NULL))**
  AND ((TP.PHASE_CODE STARTING WITH ?) OR **(? IS NULL))**
ORDER BY TP.PHASE_CODE
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I read somewhere that all options in a drop down list can be shown when a blank parameter is selected by doing a `WHERE FIELD LIKE ‘%’ || ? || ‘%’` but so far I haven't been able to get that to work, I keep getting an "unexpected end of command" error.

Comment: You are using Firebird 2.5? If you are, which driver (+ version) are you using? It might be that the driver itself doesn't support the `SQL_NULL` datatype that is required for using `? IS NULL` without casts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not using Firebird 2.5 (but version 2.0 or higher), or if you are using a driver that doesn't support the `SQL_NULL` datatype introduced in Firebird 2.5, then you need to use an explicit `CAST`, eg;

```
SELECT *
FROM TLPE_ITEMS TI
WHERE TI.ITEM_NUMBER = ? OR CAST(? AS INTEGER) IS NULL
```

This will identify the second parameter as an `INTEGER` to the driver (and to Firebird), allowing you to set it to `NULL`.

Now the faq you reference mentions *cast the value to appropriate datatype*, what they mean is that you should not cast to a data type that might result to conversion errors if it isn't null.

In my example I cast to `INTEGER`, but if the values are actually strings and you use say `"IX0109302"` as a value, you will get a conversion error as it isn't an appropriate `INTEGER`. To prevent that, you would need to cast to a `(VAR)CHAR` of sufficient length (otherwise you get a truncation error).

If you are using Firebird 1.5 or earlier this trick will not work, see [CORE-778](http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/CORE-778), in that case you might get away with something like `TI.ITEM_NUMBER = ? OR 'T' = ?`, where you set the second parameter to either `'T'` (true) or `'F'` (false) to signal whether you want everything or not; this means that you need to move the NULL detection to your calling code.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I am using Firebird 2.0, so I will try casting to an appropriate data type.

Comment: I know my C.AREA_ID is an integer so I tried the following: `WHERE (C.AREA_ID = 1) OR (C.AREA_ID = ?) OR CAST(? AS INTEGER) IS NULL` but I still get the "data type unknown" error.

Comment: I'll see if I can reproduce it.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure how else to proceed.

Comment: I just tried a query very similar to that in my answer against Firebird 2.0.7 and it works as I expected, this is further corroborated by [CORE-778](http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/CORE-778) which says it was fixed in Firebird 2.0 beta 1). I used the Firebird JDBC driver. Which driver (+ version) are you using?

Comment: It appears to be the ODBC 2.0.1 version.

Comment: Are you sure you are actually using Firebird 2.0, and not - for example - Firebird 1.5?

Comment: Hi Mark, oops, you are right, I am actually using Firebird 1.5, not 2.0 as I originally thought...

Comment: Then I believe the only way is to upgrade to 2.0 (or better yet 2.5), or see the potential solution in my update

Comment: Thanks Mark, I will try out your solution mentioned above.